Multi-Sig Transaction not broadcasting error - Script evaluated without error but finished with a false/empty top stack element
Trying to produce a multi-sig transaction. I have this so far.
Sent funds to : 2NDiRgpVVQ3CtYMi962myja69pFW8VSJ9Yp
https://mempool.space/testnet4/address/2NDiRgpVVQ3CtYMi962myja69pFW8VSJ9Yp
I guess firstly was that the wrong address to send to?
Here is my tx hash:
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
I wrote this code to produce all this:
void Main()
{
    Network network = Network.TestNet4;
    byte[] key1Bytes = ("Removed").HexToByteArray();
    byte[] key2Bytes = ("Removed").HexToByteArray();
    byte[] key3Bytes = ("Removed").HexToByteArray();
    
    Key key1 = new Key(key1Bytes);
    Key key2 = new Key(key2Bytes);
    Key key3 = new Key(key3Bytes);

    // Create a 2-of-3 multi-sig script
    Script scriptPubKey   = PayToMultiSigTemplate.Instance.GenerateScriptPubKey(2, new[] { key1.PubKey, key2.PubKey, key3.PubKey });
    //Script redeemScript = scriptPubKey.PaymentScript;
    
    //Get deposit address '2NDiRgpVVQ3CtYMi962myja69pFW8VSJ9Yp'
    BitcoinAddress multiSigAddress = scriptPubKey.Hash.GetAddress(network);
    var sender = multiSigAddress.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("Multi-Sig Address: " + multiSigAddress);
    //cc1e708dd199b390f5103444ff0b131bbc4294ce55cfaa3e0878e41cb21abc14
    //cc0bdc3c691c263407b1060169d44fc2c59b004cd182e6aa72873f0cc389dd96
    //vout 1
    

    OutPoint outPoint = new OutPoint(uint256.Parse("cc0bdc3c691c263407b1060169d44fc2c59b004cd182e6aa72873f0cc389dd96"), 1);
    Coin coin = new Coin(outPoint, new TxOut(Money.Satoshis(500_000m), scriptPubKey));
    //ScriptCoin coinToSpend = new ScriptCoin(coin, scriptPubKey);
    
    
    var txInAmount = coinToSpend.Amount;
    var minerFee = new Money(450, MoneyUnit.Satoshi);
    var sendAmount = new Money(0.00001M, MoneyUnit.BTC);
    var totalSpend = sendAmount - minerFee;

    // Destination address
    BitcoinAddress recipientAddress = BitcoinAddress.Create("tb1qj3drgzxj7lxs0d73mmaa5c5eyjqkq8vwjx7xak", network);

    // Create the transaction
    TransactionBuilder builder = network.CreateTransactionBuilder();
    TransactionBuilder builderForKey1 = network.CreateTransactionBuilder();
    TransactionBuilder builderForKey2 = network.CreateTransactionBuilder();

    NBitcoin.Transaction unsigned = builder
        .AddCoins(coin)
        .Send(recipientAddress, totalSpend)
        .SendFees(minerFee)
        .SetChange(multiSigAddress)
        .SetOptInRBF(true)
        .BuildTransaction(false);

    NBitcoin.Transaction key1Signed =
        builderForKey1
        .AddCoins(coin)
        .AddKeys(key1)
        .SignTransaction(unsigned);

    NBitcoin.Transaction key2Signed =
        builderForKey2
        .AddCoins(coin)
        .AddKeys(key2)
        .SignTransaction(key1Signed);

    NBitcoin.Transaction fullySigned =
        builder
        .AddCoins(coin)
        .CombineSignatures(key1Signed, key2Signed);


    var txVerified = builder.Verify(fullySigned);
    var result = fullySigned.Check();


    txVerified.Dump();
        result.Dump();

    var hexTx = fullySigned.ToHex();
    var hashTX = fullySigned.GetHash();
    hexTx.Dump();

    //Console.WriteLine(fullySigned);

//  var hexTx = fullySigned.ToHex();
//  var hashTX = fullySigned.GetHash();
//
//  hexTx.Dump();
    //BroadcastTransaction(fullySigned);
}
public static decimal BTCMultiplier = 100_000_000M;

void BroadcastTransaction(NBitcoin.Transaction transaction)
{
    using (var node = Node.Connect(Network.TestNet4, "Removed"))
    {
        node.VersionHandshake();
        node.SendMessage(new InvPayload(InventoryType.MSG_TX, transaction.GetHash()));
        node.SendMessage(new TxPayload(transaction));
        Thread.Sleep(500); // Wait a bit to ensure the transaction is sent
    }
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static byte[] HexToByteArray(this string hex)
    {
        var bytes = Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length / 2)
                .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16))
                .ToArray();

        return bytes;
    }
}

I am kind of at a loss and the transaction passes both the verify and the check, but when I go to broadcast in CLI I get Script evaluated without error but finished with a false/empty top stack element)
Any help is appreciated.
Updated code to reflect the address 2NDiRgpVVQ3CtYMi962myja69pFW8VSJ9Yp

Ok, so for those wanting to see what I did. Here is the following code that IS working:
void Main()
{
    Network network = Network.TestNet4;
    byte[] key1Bytes = ("Removed").HexToByteArray();
    byte[] key2Bytes = ("Removed").HexToByteArray();
    byte[] key3Bytes = ("Removed").HexToByteArray();
    
    Key key1 = new Key(key1Bytes);
    Key key2 = new Key(key2Bytes);
    Key key3 = new Key(key3Bytes);

    // Create a 2-of-3 multi-sig script
    Script scriptPubKey   = PayToMultiSigTemplate.Instance.GenerateScriptPubKey(2, new[] { key1.PubKey, key2.PubKey, key3.PubKey });
    Script redeemScript = scriptPubKey.PaymentScript;
    
    BitcoinAddress multiSigAddress = scriptPubKey.Hash.GetAddress(network);
    var sender = multiSigAddress.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("Multi-Sig Address: " + multiSigAddress);
    //cc1e708dd199b390f5103444ff0b131bbc4294ce55cfaa3e0878e41cb21abc14
    //cc0bdc3c691c263407b1060169d44fc2c59b004cd182e6aa72873f0cc389dd96
    //vout 1
    

    OutPoint outPoint = new OutPoint(uint256.Parse("cc0bdc3c691c263407b1060169d44fc2c59b004cd182e6aa72873f0cc389dd96"), 1);
    Coin coin = new Coin(outPoint, new TxOut(Money.Satoshis(500_000m), redeemScript));
    ScriptCoin coinToSpend = new ScriptCoin(coin, scriptPubKey);
    
    
    var txInAmount = coin.Amount;
    var minerFee = new Money(450, MoneyUnit.Satoshi);
    var sendAmount = new Money(0.00001M, MoneyUnit.BTC);
    var totalSpend = sendAmount - minerFee;

    // Destination address
    BitcoinAddress recipientAddress = BitcoinAddress.Create("tb1qj3drgzxj7lxs0d73mmaa5c5eyjqkq8vwjx7xak", network);

    // Create the transaction
    TransactionBuilder builder = network.CreateTransactionBuilder();
    TransactionBuilder builderForKey1 = network.CreateTransactionBuilder();
    TransactionBuilder builderForKey2 = network.CreateTransactionBuilder();

    NBitcoin.Transaction unsigned = builder
        .AddCoins(coinToSpend)
        .Send(recipientAddress, totalSpend)
        .SendFees(minerFee)
        .SetChange(multiSigAddress)
        .SetOptInRBF(true)
        .BuildTransaction(false);

    NBitcoin.Transaction key1Signed =
        builderForKey1
        .AddCoins(coinToSpend)
        .AddKeys(key1)
        .SignTransaction(unsigned);

    NBitcoin.Transaction key2Signed =
        builderForKey2
        .AddCoins(coinToSpend)
        .AddKeys(key2)
        .SignTransaction(key1Signed);

    NBitcoin.Transaction fullySigned =
        builder
        .AddCoins(coinToSpend)
        .CombineSignatures(key1Signed, key2Signed);


    var txVerified = builder.Verify(fullySigned);
    var result = fullySigned.Check();


    txVerified.Dump();
        result.Dump();

    var hexTx = fullySigned.ToHex();
    var hashTX = fullySigned.GetHash();
    hexTx.Dump();

    //Console.WriteLine(fullySigned);

//  var hexTx = fullySigned.ToHex();
//  var hashTX = fullySigned.GetHash();
//
//  hexTx.Dump();
    //BroadcastTransaction(fullySigned);
}
public static decimal BTCMultiplier = 100_000_000M;

void BroadcastTransaction(NBitcoin.Transaction transaction)
{
    using (var node = Node.Connect(Network.TestNet4, "BTCNodeIpGoesHere"))
    {
        node.VersionHandshake();
        node.SendMessage(new InvPayload(InventoryType.MSG_TX, transaction.GetHash()));
        node.SendMessage(new TxPayload(transaction));
        Thread.Sleep(500); // Wait a bit to ensure the transaction is sent
    }
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static byte[] HexToByteArray(this string hex)
    {
        var bytes = Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length / 2)
                .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16))
                .ToArray();

        return bytes;
    }
}

You can see the TX worked here: https://mempool.space/testnet4/tx/800f4031f65eb141fc7083d89a29c6987da75c6d282ccb2bc72673e219d027ad
Now that I understand how to do a basic MS, I will attempt to use PSBTs for better support and cleaner code.
This was done in C# and with a modified version of NBitcoin to support Testnet4.

The correct address, derived from the redeem script in your transaction, is actually 2NDiRgpVVQ3CtYMi962myja69pFW8VSJ9Yp. Both of these recently received 500,000 testnet sats, you must have mixed them up.

well I wasn't sure which one was correct. so I tried with both. I will switch everything to use that and report code. Let me know if you see any issues.

I have update source code and information above. I still get the same error, so I must be constructing the TX wrong is all I can think. Any ideas?

I believe I see my errors. Thank you for assistance.


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

Looking at this transaction data, there is no P2SH redeem script set at the last of script_sig.
You need to set the redeem script for the P2SH address 2NDiRgpVVQ3CtYMi962myja69pFW8VSJ9Yp.

Hey thank you for comment. I figured out was I was doing and posted the response below. You are correct I have  my redeem and scriptpubs mixed up and once sorted TXs were being approved and confirmed
